# Android Studio Error - chaquo.python.PyException: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, android, kotlin, filenotfoundexception, chaquopy

I'm trying to open a text file in Android Studio through Python. I configured chaquo plugin in the IDE and I'm able to run a simple program like "Hello World" without issues. However when I try to open an external file I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: com.chaquo.python.PyException: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/.../app/src/main/python/text.txt'
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

I've included my build.gradle file which contains code added to install the chaquopy plugin For reference I used https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html

Here's my files-

test.py:

```
from os.path import dirname, join

def tt():

filename = join(dirname(__file__), "text.txt")
f = open(filename, "r")
print(f.read())
return filename
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import com.chaquo.python.Python
import com.chaquo.python.android.AndroidPlatform

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var test: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    test = findViewById(R.id.t)

    initPython()
}

private fun initPython() {
    if (!Python.isStarted()) {
        Python.start(AndroidPlatform(this))
    }
    val python = Python.getInstance()
    val pythonFile = python.getModule("test")
    val obj = pythonFile.callAttr("tt")
    test.text = obj.toString()
}
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.chaquo.python'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        sourceSets {
            main {
                python {
                    srcDirs = ["src/main/python"]
                    python.srcDirs = ["src/main/python"]
                }
            }
        }
        python {
            buildPython "C:/.../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe"
            buildPython "python3"
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility kotlin_version
        targetCompatibility kotlin_version
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    ndkVersion '21.1.6352462'
}
```

Comment: check the location of text.txt and see if it matches with the path in which it is trying to find.

Comment: @PiyushMaheswari I already checked that. The path which I provided is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's running on the emulator, an Android app still has no access to files on your development machine. They're effectively two separate devices.

However, any data file in your Python source directory will be copied into your APK and extracted onto the Android device. You can then access it using a path relative to `__file__`, as shown [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/144).

Comment: Thanks that worked! my `__file__`  variable gives the following path:                                                                        /data/user/0/com.dev.user.tennisapp/files/chaquopy/AssetFinder/app/text.txt                        Would you know where to locate this in file explorer?

Comment: Use the Android Studio [Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer).